# Validate input element by required attribute and get the label text for each input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML code inside a form and I need to check whether fields with `required="required"` attribute are empty or not. Pretty much HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="p_name">
    <label class="required" for="product_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="50" required="required" name="product[name]" id="product_name">
</div>
```

I'm building this code:

```
$('input[required="required"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        // Here I should get the text of the label element for 
        // each input and write in the alert but don't know how
        alert();
    }
});
```

Form elements are wrapped by some section element with `id` for example `#product-create-step-3` so based on what section elements are I should check only fields within the active section, can any give me some help on this code since I don't get how to get the label text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tahnq/)

```
$('input[required="required"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        var lbl = $(this).siblings('label');
        //or var lbl = $(this).prev('label');
        alert(lbl.text());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If the HTML structure for all your fields is the same as you have posted, you can use, `.prev()`:

```
$('input[required="required"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        alert($(this).prev('label').text() + ' is required...');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) selector along with [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to extract the text because the `label` element is the previous sibling of the input element in question

```
$('input[required="required"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
        // Here I should get the text of the label element for 
        // each input and write in the alert but don't know how
        alert($(this).prev().text() + ' cannot be blank');
    }
});
```